# Grab client-side field value in server-side JavaScript in XPages

Tags: client-side, xpages, xpages-ssjs

I seem to be missing something with XPages.  I have a button that has server side JS which is attempting to get the value from the 2 existing fields on the document.  I enter values in the form and the field values are empty when the button is clicked.

```
var doc:NotesDocument = currentDocument.getDocument();
var email = doc.getItemValue("email");
_dump("Email: " + email);
var password = doc.getItemValue("password");
_dump("Password: " + password);
```

I can see the values are empty in my log.nsf by using the "_dump" command.

When I use client side JS to grab the fields, they are populated -- I can see in the alert statements:

```
var doc = document;
var email = doc.getElementById("#{id:email1}").value;
alert(email);
var password = doc.getElementById("#{id:password1}").value;
alert(password);
```

I tried a partial refresh on the panel where the email and password fields exist, but that still didn't help.

Do I have to save the document first and grab the document again to get the field values?  Do I have to pass the field values in client side JS and then pass in a scope (I don't think that can be done from client side JS)?  It is probably a simple solution but I am not sure why this is happening.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Retrieve the values directly from the data source:

```
var email = currentDocument.getValue("email");
var password = currentDocument.getValue("password");
```

Comment: +1, also you need to be careful when you grab them. E.g. if a validation fails the values are not posted back to the document and you have to go after the component.getsubmittedValue

Comment: The getSubmittedValue worked great. I actually used this snippet (http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=getcomponentvalue) and it is pulling the field value.  I appreciate all the help - thanks!